# Seperating dev and prod output files in webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm creating a browser app using NodeJS + Webpack 5 and I want to seperate the output directories of the dev and production bundle scripts. Currently both of them compile to ./dist/bundle.js but I want the `npm run prod` to compile to ./dist/prod.js

**package.json**

```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },  

  ???
  outputProduction: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'prod.js'
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According with this https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/ you can access environment variables on the webpack config file.

So maybe you can do something like this:

```
  module.exports = (env) => {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: env.production ? 'prod.js' : 'bundle.js'
  },
```

I hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: Tysm! Exactly what I needed

Comment: I'm glad to help my friend

Comment: You can also give me an upward vote, if you think this answer can help others too. Thanks bro.